# CakePHP: What is the best way to create a function I can call from a .ctp template file?

Tags: templates, cakephp

I need to execute a function in a template file that checks whether a string starts with any number of strings in an array. What would be best practice?
In Magento, there is this thing called a Block file I could associate with a template file in order to call certain functions from the template file. There are also options to make use of a Helper function. Still, using a Block function is better practice in Magento.

Comment: You're either looking for Elements or View Cells, check the cake docs on both to see if they fit your needs.

Comment: A helper might also be an option for you. Or even just create a "utility" namespace somewhere to put general purpose functions.